# How can I set the data on this component when inside a parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I have this child component that will end up in a parent component. I need to update the state or send data to the child one a function finishes in the parent ( a button in the parent is pushed.)

```
const SenViewer = (data) => {
  const [sen, setSen] = useState({
    sens: [],
  });

  this.setSen({ sens: data });
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.sens.map((user) => (
        <Card className='text-center'>
          <Card.Header>
            Ticket: <p>Sen </p>
          </Card.Header>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>
              <p>Entire Audio</p>
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              Magnitude:
              <p>{user.id}</p>
              Score
              <p>{user.total}</p>
            </Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
          <Card.Footer className='text-muted'>
            <Button variant='primary'>TODO: smiley if good total</Button>
          </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}; // end of component
```

Here is the render for the parent.

```
<Parent>
   <SenViewer />
</Parent>
```

Comment: You'd pass a property to the child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you parent component create a state, which will hold the data you want to send.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [data,setData] = React.useState({});

   React.useEffect(()=> {
      setData({name:'sd'});
   },[setData]);
   
  return <div>
           <SenViewer data={data} />
      </div>
}
```

In Child Component, use it like this

```
const SanViewer = (props)=> {
  console.log(props.data) // received data from parent
}
```

Read more about props here
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data to the child component via props. Also, you don't need to set that data again in the state of the child component, unless there is some stateful work that needs to be done within the child.

```js
<Parent>
   <SenViewer data={parentData} /> 
</Parent>
```

Here `parentData` is something which `<Parent />` manages, and now child can use that information to do what it needs to do.

A simple sample of the parent in this case would be,

```js
const Parent = () => { 
  const [parentData, setParentData] = useState({});
  return (
    <div>
      <button value='click me' onClick={() => setParentData({someData: 'foo'})}></button>
      <SenViewer data={parentData} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: OK. I'm not sure which part of the code this is, cos you have not posted that code in your answer. Also, you posted function components based code and now you mention this.setSentiment which looks like a class component. Can you please provide the proper code so I can check what is happenin.